# Dif drive robot jumps

Tags: ros2, gazebo-11

I have a 4-wheeled cart robot in Gazebo. When driving over obstacle, accelerating/breaking or changing direction abruptly, it gets into about 10 secs resonance: just imagine that you drive by hitting break, then accelerator, then break again... It goes to front wheels (break) then to rear wheels (acceleration)... At a constant speed. So it is just an instability of... I don't know. Either drive, or the parameters, like inertia...
My question is, how to fix it? I can try altering ALL parameters, but I would rather understand the reason first...
Thank you.